# Does polars preserve row order in a left join?

Tags: python, join, python-polars

Consider the following polars dataframes:

```py
>>> left = pl.DataFrame(pl.Series('a', [1,5,3,2]))
>>> left
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ a   │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 1   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   │
└─────┘
>>> right = pl.DataFrame([pl.Series('a', [0,1,2,3]), pl.Series('b', [4,5,6,7])])
>>> right
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 0   ┆ 4   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 6   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 7   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I would like to join the two in such a way that the order of the `a` values from the `left` dataframe is preserved. A left join seems to do this:

```py
>>> left.join(right, on='a', how='left')
shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬──────┐
│ a   ┆ b    │
│ --- ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ i64  │
╞═════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 5   ┆ null │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 7    │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 6    │
└─────┴──────┘
```

My question is: is this behaviour guaranteed? If not, what would be the safe way to do this? I could use `with_row_count` and then do a final sort, but that seems rather cumbersome. In pandas this can be done concisely with the `reindex` method.

Comment: I've always assumed this is guaranteed - I've never seen it behave any other way. Hopefully someone can confirm it officially.

Comment: Why do you assume that pandas `reindex` is more efficient than `with_row_index` and `sort` in polars?  I'll give you that it's more concise but more efficient?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor, fair call. I did not do any speed comparisons. I've removed the claims about efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

A left join guarantees preserving the order of the left dataframe, at least in the regular engine. For the streaming engine, this might not be guaranteed.

If you want to be 'safe', you already have the right workaround in mind to add a row count and sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

No, order is not guaranteed to be kept. I ran into it recently and managed to replicate the behavior with a small example:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df1 = pl.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(100), 'foo': np.random.rand(100)})
df1.head()
```

This will show

```
shape: (5, 2)
id  foo
i64 f64
0   0.620648
1   0.81778
2   0.132117
3   0.07644
4   0.047929
```

Now let's create a second dataframe with scrambled ids:

```
shuffled_id = np.random.choice(np.arange(100), 100, replace=False)
df2 = pl.DataFrame({'id': shuffled_id, 'bar': np.random.rand(100)})

df2.head()
```

which contains

```
shape: (5, 2)
id  bar
i64 f64
80  0.674931
71  0.166214
49  0.990646
24  0.82716
22  0.808711
```

Now let's join them:

```
df1.join(df2, on='id')
```

And now the ordering is neither the one in `df1` or `df2`:

```
shape: (100, 3)
id  foo bar
i64 f64 f64
93  0.476374    0.147519
22  0.760892    0.499682
30  0.167688    0.221052
94  0.429656    0.389314
16  0.304306    0.469522
13  0.624806    0.003972
50  0.429345    0.268665
...
```

Comment: The title of the question should probably be edited as it is specifically talking about a left join e.g. `how="left"`.

Comment: Agreed. Changed the title.

Comment: And to be clear, the `how` parameter defaults to `inner` which doesn't guarantee ordering (as your example shows)